# CoreOS AWS userdata "docker run" on startup won't run

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos, user-data

I'm trying to setup CoreOS on AWS to run specific commands on boot to download our DCOS cluster's info tarball and run scripts contained within it. These scripts help add the instance as an "agent" to our DC/OS cluster.

However, I don't seem to be able to get the *docker run* commands to run. I do see that the userdata is creating the tee's output file (which remains empty) and also the /opt/dcos_install_tmp/ directory (also remains empty).

The docker run commands here download an "awscli" container, fetch packages from S3 (using IAM instance profile credentials), and spit it out to the CoreOS file system.

Installing AWS CLI on CoreOS didn't seem straightforward (there's no package manager, no python), so I had to resort to this.

If I login to the instance and run the same commands by putting them in a script, I have absolutely no issues.

I check "journalctl --identifier=coreos-cloudinit" and found nothing to indicate issues. It just reports:

```
 15:58:34 Parsing user-data as script
```

There is no "boot" log file for CoreOS in /var/log/ unlike in other AMIs.

I'm really stuck right now and would love some nudges in the right direction.

Here's my userdata (which I post as text during instance boot):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/docker run -it --name cli governmentpaas/awscli aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/dcos/dcos_preconfig.sh /root && /usr/bin/docker cp cli:/root/dcos_preconfig.sh . && /usr/bin/docker rm cli | tee -a /root/userdatalog.txt

/usr/bin/docker run -it --name cli governmentpaas/awscli aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/dcos/dcos-install.tar /root && /usr/bin/docker cp cli:/root/dcos-install.tar . && /usr/bin/docker rm cli | tee -a /root/userdatalog.txt

sudo mkdir -p /opt/dcos_install_tmp

sudo tar xf dcos-install.tar -C /opt/dcos_install_tmp | tee -a /root/userdatalog.txt

sudo /bin/bash /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh slave | tee -a /root/userdatalog.txt
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar issue on Digital Ocean.  My docker run also appears not to execute even though the rest of my script does.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924883/digitalocean-how-to-run-docker-command-on-newly-created-droplet-via-java-api

Comment: I gave up and moved to CentOS. Would have loved to have CoreOS work for us.

Answer (score 2):

Remove -t flag from the docker run command.

I had a similar problem: [DigitalOcean: How to run Docker command on newly created Droplet via Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924883/digitalocean-how-to-run-docker-command-on-newly-created-droplet-via-java-api/40932011#40932011)
The problem ended up being the -t flag in the docker run command. Apparently this doesn't work because it isn't a terminal or something like that. Remove the flag and it runs fine.