# DigitalOcean: How to run Docker command on newly created Droplet via Java API

Tags: java, docker, digital-ocean, user-data

I'm trying to create a new Droplet and then kick off a Docker command via a UserData bash script.  I set the user data via the Java API when creating the droplet and observe that the test files and logs I made are created.

```
newDroplet.setUserData("#!/bin/bash\n" +
            "touch /test.txt;"+
            "docker login --username=myname--password=mypass > /loginlog;"+
            "docker pull mybuild > /pulllog;"+
            "docker run --log-opt max-size=1g --net host --name myserver -t -i mybuild > /runlog;");
```

loginlog and pulllog both show successful outcomes.  However nothing exists in the file runlog.

I can ssh into the droplet and then run the exact same docker command and it runs as expected.  Why can't it be run from a userdata script?  Why is no output generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being the -t flag in the docker run command.  Apparently this doesn't work because it isn't a terminal or something like that.  Remove the flag and it runs fine.